# Can we retrive XAML UI Code in code behind c#?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have created a control and have added to ContentPage.Content in C#. Now can we retrieve XAML complete UI code from the Content? I have to save this Xamarin form ui code in PostgreSQL database.

StackLayout parent = null;

Add any children (label, entry etc.) in the parent.

Content = new ScrollView { Content = parent };

Then get xaml code from Content. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for XamlWriter which is not available in Xamarin.Forms.
The only thing you can actually do is to read and parse a XAML string, but that is just the opposite of your goal.

You can however serialize your XF view and save it to database. Plain serialization will generate a ton of trash (properties) you don't actually need, but instead you could create your own serialization mechanism to generate a simple model with just the view properties you need.